# Docker compose won't connect Node.js app to Postgres even when host is right

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize a simple Node.js MVC app that uses PostgreSQL.

My docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./src/db/db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql

  app:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: on-failure
    links:
      - postgres
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      USER: postgres
      HOST: postgres
      DB: postgres
      PASS: postgres
      PORT: 5432
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY ./src /home/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node server.js"]
```

And the object I use as config to connect to the database:

```
const { Client } = require("pg");
const conObject = {
  user: process.env.USER,
  host: process.env.HOST,
  database: process.env.DB,
  password: process.env.PASS,
  port: +process.env.PORT,
  createTableMissing: true,
};

const client = new Client(conObject);
client.connect();
```

As you can see, I listened to the advice from the internet and for the host of the database declared its container name, but the problem is that the app can't connect to it.

The logs from the web app:

```
2023-01-26 19:10:41 App started on port 3000
2023-01-26 19:10:41 (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.16.2:5432
2023-01-26 19:10:41     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
2023-01-26 19:10:41 (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2023-01-26 19:10:41 (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2023-01-26 19:10:41 (node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

2023-01-26 19:10:41 Failed to prune sessions: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.16.2:5432
```